# Spring RestController endpoints all redirected to '/' root route

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a rest endpoint that looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "api/profile/majors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMajors() {
  //return profileDAO.getMajors();
  return "abc";
}
```

For some reason, everytime I go to the browser and visit:`http://localhost:8080/api/profile/majors`
it seems the request is always redirected to `http://localhost:8080`

When I put a break point at `return "abc"`, the program does stop there, but the response sent back to browser is still whatever is at `http://localhost:8080/`

Any idea why??

(A little more background: I do have Spring Security filters running, I did call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` but this problem still occur..)

Any hint would be helpful!

My security config is like so:

```
http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(Endpoints.PROTECTED_API_PATTERN)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new JWTLoginFilter(loginRequestMatcher, authenticationManager(), successHandler),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                )
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new JWTAPIFilter(protectedAPIMatcher, authenticationManager(), cookieService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                );
```

Comment: What is the response code you are getting when accessing `http://localhost:8080/api/profile/majors` ?

Comment: It was 302 Found

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/profile/majors
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: I don't remember correctly. But this might be after login was successful, you were directed to this page. Maybe share spring security config here too.

Comment: I have a custom filter that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and I passed `"/api/**"` to its constructor's `defaultFilterProcessesUrl`. If I set this to any other value like just `"/"` everything just works... Any idea?

Comment: Shared security config above

Answer (score 0):

Try using a slash at the beginning of your path. Your code should look like

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/profile/majors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: My problem seems to be with the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter `'s `defaultFilterProcessesUrl `... Please see comments above..Not sure how to why it happens yet..

Answer (score -2):

You can try to add @ResponseBody above your method getMajors.

Comment: My problem seems to be with the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter `'s `defaultFilterProcessesUrl `... Please see comments above..Not sure how to why it happens yet